# how to disable load css stylesheet url

Tags: javascript, css

I use Font-Awesome css I need a way to force browsers to disable load the link.

How to disable load this link:`<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">`.

Comment: Remove it from the markup?

Comment: If you have 100 tags to remove, search&replace can be a quick solution.

Comment: Disable the link for all users, some users, by default, in response to an event..?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove a stylesheet from the DOM using JavaScript if you know part of the `href` that will only be in that particular link element:

```
document.querySelector("link[rel=stylesheet][href~=font-awesome]").outerHTML = "";
```

This will remove the first link element that is a stylesheet and that contains "font-awesome" somewhere in the link.

Answer (score -2):

You can comment the link or simply remove it.